# есть ли библиотека (на python) для конфигурирования supervisor?

Tags: python, supervisord

Искал, но не могу найти какого-либо решения, чтобы из python скрипта конфигурировать supervisor, например добавлять новые конфигурации.
Может быть кто сталкивался с такой задачей?

Comment: чтобы например скрипт выкачивал из БД конфигурации и отправлял в supervisord

Comment: Конфиг supervisord - обычные файлы, функции создания и записи файлов в питоне есть, какие проблемы?

Comment: всё файлы, не хочется делать велосипед, м.б. есть какое-то решение, обрабатывать ошибки конфигурации, делать рестарт, проверять сделался ли рестарт, много работы

Comment: А для рестартов и проверок есть supervisorctl.И наверняка у supervisord есть какой-нибудь HTTP API, но точно не в курсе